# Is there a better way to write 'pre processing and post processing'?

Tags: grammaticality

Can *pre processing and post processing* be replaced with *pre and post processing*? Is it grammatically correct?

Comment: *pre processing* and *post processing* do not exist. It is *[preprocessing](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/preprocessing)* and *[postprocessing](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/postprocessing)* (with *pre-processing* and *post-processing* listed as alternative spellings).

Answer (score 10):

Your example is grammatical, but it might be better to write *pre- and post-processing* so that it's obvious that *pre-* is a prefix for processing also.

Comment: Would "pre- and postprocessing" also be acceptable?

Comment: @Alexander yes.